# html required attribute does not work

Tags: html, angular-cli, required

I use Angular cli for a simple form to submit, however, the required attributes in the input elements do not work, I can still submit the form without inputting anything, even though they are wrapped in the form element. I googled the solutions, but somehow I can't still figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Here is the html code:

```
<form (submit)="onAddSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>City</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="city" name="city" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Owner</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="owner" name="owner" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Bedrooms</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" required>
      <option value="Estate">Estate</option>
      <option value="Condo">Condo</option>
      <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="image" name="image" [(ngModel)]="image" type="file" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="price" name="price" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Comment: I have executed your program and it requires all fields and it works well. You can check your code on online tool like https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/GhqFH

Comment: Yes, I know that it works when it stands alone and absolutely no error, but when I integrated in Angular 2, it did not work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reactive form from angular to achieve validation. Please refer following example.

```
import { 
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstname: ['', Validators.required],
    lastname: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
}


Html template

<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
  <label>Firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstname">
  <p *ngIf="registerForm.controls.firstname.errors">This field is required!</p>

   <label>Lastname:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="lastname">
  <p *ngIf="registerForm.controls.lastname.errors">This field is required!</p>

</form>
```

Comment: the ngIf directive does not work properly, this text "This field is required!" always show in any case. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes you need to add one more check to identify field is touched or not like *ngIf="lastname.invalid && (lastname.dirty || lastname.touched)"

Comment: By the way how to do the passwords 'confirmation by this reactive forms?

Comment: Please provide complete requirement related to password confirmation, did you mean we have to match password and confirm password fields?

Comment: Yes, but I figured it out, thank you for your quick reply anyway :)